# NodeJS - Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available AWS Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, next.js, next.js13

I'm running a container on an image that works perfectly locally. Only on AWS (App Runner or ECS) I get this error message: NodeJS - Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available.

Answer (score 0):

I executed env on my container running locally and I got the follo

`
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

HOSTNAME=8f5a4bb46f85

NODE_VERSION=18.16.0

YARN_VERSION=1.22.19

NODE_ENV=production

NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

PORT=3000

HOME=/home/nextjs
`

For some reason if we don't set HOSTNAME as an env on AWS it throws that error. Setting PORT and HOSTNAME fixed that.

Comment: what did you end up setting the HOSTNAME to in AWS?

Comment: @Rob do you mean why? For some reason setting the hostname would fix that.